# Unity Animator State Freezing

Tags: unity, android, animation

I am really new with Unity, I am making a game, but I am having some problems with the animators, my problem is that I am trying to add some animations to my menu, and also add new characters to my game, but none of my new animations are working. This question is the same like these ones :

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/717046/animator-state-freezing-blue-bar-progress-bar-not.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/778616/animator-state-freezing.html

The animator freezes when I run the game.

What is really interesting is that the first animation that I created in the game works correctly. I have tried several things, but nothing works. I really need help with this.

I'm using several plug ins on this development: facebook, ngui and admod

This is the list of things that I tried:

- Create a new level, without any ngui component. I added a new animator to an empty game object and I created a sprite animation.
- I tried to move the whole project to a new one, the result was the same problem.
- I added a the animator to the object programmatically using a script. It correctly added the animator, but the result was the same.
- I tried to change properties of the project, but It seems to not work at all.
- I started a new project and followed the same steps to add the same animation, in the project everything works, but I want to avoid to created the whole project again It will take me a lot of time since I have to recreated everything to ensure this problem will not happened again.

[image]

As an addition I want to mention that in the beginning everything works correctly but suddenly the animations stopped working. As I say there is only one animator that is working, and this one was the first one that I created.

Comment: Can you provide information as to how you are assigning animators to your game objects? You have an error in your screen shot saying that the animator is not instantiated.

Comment: Yes, I just go to the animation option, in this case are sprites I create a new animation and drag the sprites to the object, test the animation and finally I check if the controller was created. The error that is displayed happens when I manually changes the default state when the game is running.

Comment: Do you have a script that starts the animation or is it just supposed to run upon starting and you find that it doesn't run?

Comment: The animation must run when the level starts, but it doesn't run, if I check the animator the default state is freeze the progress bar isn't moving at all. I tried with script but the result is always the same.

Comment: Based on the final bullet it sounds like something in your existing project might be causing the problem. I don't think we can really help you with your issue since you claim that from an empty project your process and assets seem to work fine. I know you don't want to but I would step by step add your add ons and remaining assets / scripts back into the project to see where the problem lies. Alternatively you could remove things one by one in your existing project until the issue is resolved. If its something that would be useful to others post it as an answer here when you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think as you that the solution of this problem is to start with a new one. I will comment my progress with this, and maybe I will be able to answer this question and help somebody with the same problem.